# Amule does not want to launch?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, update-manager, downloads, torrent-client

after I did reboot my system (required for an update), well, amule simply refuse to launch...

I tried uninstall/reinstall then reboot, but I still have the problem, anyone can explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please open a terminal window, type `amule`, and press enter? Then let us know what error messages appear on the screen. Thank you.

Comment: 2016-05-05 12:52:05: Initialising aMule SVN compiled with wxGTK2 v3.0.2 and Boost 1.58
 2016-05-05 12:52:05: Checking if there is an instance already running...
!2016-05-05 12:52:05: There is an instance of aMule already running
 2016-05-05 12:52:05: (lock file: /home/leon/.aMule/muleLock)
 2016-05-05 12:52:05: Raising current running instance.

Comment: Try running `sudo killall amule` and opening amule again. If that doesn't work, reboot and try opening amule again. Does that fix it or do you still get the same message?

Comment: leon@leon-GU506AA-B14-a6240-be:/$ sudo killall amule
amule: no process found
leon@leon-GU506AA-B14-a6240-be:/$ amule
 2016-05-05 18:17:37: Initialising aMule SVN compiled with wxGTK2 v3.0.2 and Boost 1.58
 2016-05-05 18:17:37: Checking if there is an instance already running...
!2016-05-05 18:17:37: There is an instance of aMule already running
 2016-05-05 18:17:37: (lock file: /home/leon/.aMule/muleLock)
 2016-05-05 18:17:37: Raising current running instance.
leon@leon-GU506AA-B14-a6240-be:/$

Comment: Tried everything, still not working. Should I delete the Lock file?

Comment: Yes, try deleting the lock file and see if that fixes the problem.